# Writing directives in the link function of a directive in angular-js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have defined a directive in angular.js.  That directive has a link function and a controller  function, and no template, so all the view is generated in the link function.  In the link function I am doing the following:

```
var button=angular.element("<a>");
button.addClass("ng-click: previousLink();");

//previousLink() is a function defined in the scope.
//I am doing it like that, because before that one I attempted to do:
//button.prop("ng-click", "previousLink()");
//button.text("Previous");
//but for some reason it was showing on html as <a>Next</a>, without adding the property.
```

It does not work. If I click the button it does nothing. If, instead of doing this in the link function in code I were doing it using a template, it would work.  For some reason I need to make some manipulations using jquery in the link function.  What should I do? Is there anyway to make this work, or would I have to use both template and link function and combine things there?

Comment: `ng-click` is not written into markup as a class, it is written as an attribute.

If you are going to manipulate the html in a way that you expect angular to interpret it you need to use `$compile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `$compile` you need to follow your existing code with something like:

```
$compile(button.contents())(scope);
```

If you want it to be dynamic, you can put this inside a `$watch` like so:

```
link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
  scope.$watch(attrs.yourval, function(html) {
    var button=angular.element("<a>");
    button.addClass("ng-click: previousLink();");
    $compile(button.contents())(scope);
  });
}
```

`$compile` attaches the scope (supplied as a parameter) to the html you have defined. This will make your button clicks work properly.